# How to call middleware in laravel custom package and authenticate

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I am working on a module/package base application. I created a middleware `RoleMiddleware` and I have also attached the picture of my directories.

```
app
 /Http
  /Middleware
   /RoleMiddleware.php
```

I have the following directory of my custom package

```
 app
   /package
    /cases  (This is the package name)
     /src
      /Http
       /Controllers
        /CaseController.php
```

now I want to call my `RoleMiddleware` in my packager controller constructor but role middleware not working in constructor how can I do that the following middleware when call with `web.php` rote in my package returns `null` but if I route in default `web.php` file returns me the null.

RoleMiddlware defiend in Default Middlware Folder

```
class RoleMiddleware
    {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd(Auth::user());
        if (Auth::check() === false) {
            return redirect('login');
        } elseif (Auth::check() === true) {

            dd('hi');

            $roles = Role::all()->pluck('slug');

            if (is_null($request->user())) {
                abort(404);
            }
            if (!$request->user()->hasRole($roles)) {
                abort(404);
            }

            if ($request->user()) {
                if ($request->user()->hasRole($roles)) {
                    return $next($request);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Case Controller Defiend in Package   `app/cases/Http/controller/caseController.php`

```
class CaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('role',['except' => 'caseUrlView']);


    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['portal'] = Portal::all();
        $data['operators'] = Operator::all();

        return view('cases::case', $data);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You have to add the `package` namespace into your `composer.json` file, did you do that?

Comment: yes i do add namespace in composer.json file

 `  "autoload-dev": {`
       ` "psr-4": {`
           `"Abdullah\\cases\\": "package/cases/src/",`
        `   }`
    `},`
`

Comment: Ok. how about `dump-autoload`, did you also do that?